# Remaining deprecation notices with Pomm

Tags: model, deprecated, pomm

I use Pomm in the Symfony project in version 3.4. That's my problem, when i execute the PHpunit test from my project, i have a notices on my models files, examples :

1x: The PommProject\SymfonyBridge\PropertyInfo\Extractor\PommExtractor class is deprecated since version 2.3 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the PommProject\SymfonyBridge\PropertyInfo\Extractor\TypeExtractor class instead.
1x in TotoModelTest::testModel from App\Tests\Infrastructure\Model\MyDb\PublicSchema

1x: The "App\Infrastructure\Model\MyDb\PublicSchema\TotoModel" service is private, getting it from the container is deprecated since Symfony 3.2 and will fail in 4.0. You should either make the service public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.
1x in TotoModelTest::testModel from App\Tests\Infrastructure\Model\MyDb\PublicSchema

What did I do?

Answer (score 1):

> PommExtractor class is deprecated

It’s difficult to anwser without code. If you use `PommExtractor` class in your code, just use `TypeExtractor` instead. Otherwise find which requirement uses it and update it (or open an issue).

> service is private, getting it from the container is deprecated

This is a symfony notice, you can read [this blog entry](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-services-are-private-by-default) to update your configuration.